# Automating python scripts

Tags: python, automation, apk, bots, web-hosting

I am interested in learning how to automate python scripts

For example: an alarm script.

If we make an alarm that is set to ring every day, this should be running every day.

I am looking to run this type of script on bots, apps, or hosting.

Comment: You better use operation system functionality such as: For Linux you have [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux), for windows you have [scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do something like running python scripts in a specific time or for example every day or every minute :

you can use [CronTab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Answer (score 0):

Try [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/), to run python functions /scripts periodically using a friendly syntax !

> pip install schedule

For more details, please visit:
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/